# How could I add class on this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I got this script to use on my project, one single page with scroll. Now my problem was everytime the page scrolled on the exact section the title always been hide by my fixed menu. Below are the script

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Hope you guys can help me. 
Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To answer your question correctly we'll need the html too. Could you provide a fiddle or a webadress shwowing your problem?

Comment: You'll need to take into account the height of the fixed header when applying `scrollTop`. Something like `scrollTop: target.offset().top + $('header').height()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You'll need to take into account the height of the fixed header when applying `scrollTop`

If my comment wan't clear enough, try this.

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
// does the pathname of this link match that of the current location.pathname?
var activeLink = (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,''));

if (activeLink || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);

    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

    if (target.length) {

         // here we will take into account the height of #navbar
         var offset = target.offset().top + $('#navbar').height();

        $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: offset // apply our new offset
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');

        return false;
    }
}
```

});